error in SoLoader when generating apk with EAS for react native
I'm running my app React Native with EXPO and, in Expo, it works correctly but, when generating the APK with EAS, it fails to open and the following log appears:
05-23 15:09:40.278  1498  3931 E ActivityTrigger: activityResumeTrigger: not whiteListedcom.matheusfinamor.Porgit/com.matheusfinamor.Porgit.MainActivity/1
05-23 15:09:40.279  1498  3931 D ActivityManager: \[MemInfo\] Process does not exist before starting ActivityRecord{c7f1376 u0 com.matheusfinamor.Porgit/.MainActivity t99741}. System free memory=1958981632
05-23 15:09:40.293  1498  3931 I ActivityManager: Start proc 3323:com.matheusfinamor.Porgit/u0a416 for activity com.matheusfinamor.Porgit/.MainActivity duration: 14
05-23 15:09:40.296  1498  3931 D ActivityManager: \[MemInfo\] Process does not exist before starting ActivityRecord{c7f1376 u0 com.matheusfinamor.Porgit/.MainActivity t99741}. System free memory=1957629952
05-23 15:09:40.380  2207  2207 D TaskWatcherService: pkgName: com.matheusfinamor.Porgit taskId: 99741
05-23 15:09:40.387  2207  2240 I AppOpsStatusUpdateHandler: pkgName = com.matheusfinamor.Porgit
05-23 15:09:40.388  2207  2207 D PowerSaverService: current package:com.matheusfinamor.Porgit, activity:com.matheusfinamor.Porgit.MainActivity, SMode:0, PMode:2
05-23 15:09:40.472  3323  3323 V Monotype: SetAppTypeFace- try to flip, app = com.matheusfinamor.Porgit
05-23 15:09:40.620  3323  3323 V Monotype: SetAppTypeFace- try to flip, app = com.matheusfinamor.Porgit
05-23 15:09:40.635  3323  3323 V SoLoader: libhermes.so not found on /data/app/com.matheusfinamor.Porgit-Xci9fNpC5ZMRhJ629ycBiw==/lib/arm64
05-23 15:09:40.641  3323  3323 V SoLoader: libjsi.so not found on /data/app/com.matheusfinamor.Porgit-Xci9fNpC5ZMRhJ629ycBiw==/lib/arm64
05-23 15:09:40.645  3323  3323 V SoLoader: libfolly_runtime.so not found on /data/app/com.matheusfinamor.Porgit-Xci9fNpC5ZMRhJ629ycBiw==/lib/arm64
05-23 15:09:40.648  3323  3323 V SoLoader: libglog.so not found on /data/app/com.matheusfinamor.Porgit-Xci9fNpC5ZMRhJ629ycBiw==/lib/arm64
05-23 15:09:40.652  3323  3323 V SoLoader: libm.so not found on /data/app/com.matheusfinamor.Porgit-Xci9fNpC5ZMRhJ629ycBiw==/lib/arm64
05-23 15:09:40.652  3323  3323 V SoLoader: libm.so not found on /data/app/com.matheusfinamor.Porgit-Xci9fNpC5ZMRhJ629ycBiw==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a
05-23 15:09:40.652  3323  3323 V SoLoader: libc++\_shared.so not found on /data/app/com.matheusfinamor.Porgit-Xci9fNpC5ZMRhJ629ycBiw==/lib/arm64
05-23 15:09:40.655  3323  3323 V SoLoader: libc.so not found on /data/app/com.matheusfinamor.Porgit-Xci9fNpC5ZMRhJ629ycBiw==/lib/arm64
05-23 15:09:40.655  3323  3323 V SoLoader: libc.so not found on /data/app/com.matheusfinamor.Porgit-Xci9fNpC5ZMRhJ629ycBiw==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a
05-23 15:09:40.655  3323  3323 V SoLoader: libdl.so not found on /data/app/com.matheusfinamor.Porgit-Xci9fNpC5ZMRhJ629ycBiw==/lib/arm64
05-23 15:09:40.655  3323  3323 V SoLoader: libdl.so not found on /data/app/com.matheusfinamor.Porgit-Xci9fNpC5ZMRhJ629ycBiw==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a
05-23 15:09:40.658  3323  3323 W linker  : "/data/app/com.matheusfinamor.Porgit-Xci9fNpC5ZMRhJ629ycBiw==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a/libc++\_shared.so" unused DT entry: type 0x70000001 arg 0x0
05-23 15:09:40.662  3323  3323 D SoLoader: libc++\_shared.so found on /data/app/com.matheusfinamor.Porgit-Xci9fNpC5ZMRhJ629ycBiw==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a
05-23 15:09:40.665  3323  3323 D SoLoader: libglog.so found on /data/app/com.matheusfinamor.Porgit-Xci9fNpC5ZMRhJ629ycBiw==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a
05-23 15:09:40.669  3323  3323 D SoLoader: libfolly_runtime.so found on /data/app/com.matheusfinamor.Porgit-Xci9fNpC5ZMRhJ629ycBiw==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a
05-23 15:09:40.671  3323  3323 D SoLoader: libjsi.so found on /data/app/com.matheusfinamor.Porgit-Xci9fNpC5ZMRhJ629ycBiw==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a
05-23 15:09:40.671  3323  3323 V SoLoader: libfbjni.so not found on /data/app/com.matheusfinamor.Porgit-Xci9fNpC5ZMRhJ629ycBiw==/lib/arm64
05-23 15:09:40.673  3323  3323 V SoLoader: libandroid.so not found on /data/app/com.matheusfinamor.Porgit-Xci9fNpC5ZMRhJ629ycBiw==/lib/arm64
05-23 15:09:40.674  3323  3323 V SoLoader: libandroid.so not found on /data/app/com.matheusfinamor.Porgit-Xci9fNpC5ZMRhJ629ycBiw==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a
05-23 15:09:40.674  3323  3323 V SoLoader: liblog.so not found on /data/app/com.matheusfinamor.Porgit-Xci9fNpC5ZMRhJ629ycBiw==/lib/arm64
05-23 15:09:40.674  3323  3323 V SoLoader: liblog.so not found on /data/app/com.matheusfinamor.Porgit-Xci9fNpC5ZMRhJ629ycBiw==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a
05-23 15:09:40.679  3323  3323 D SoLoader: libfbjni.so found on /data/app/com.matheusfinamor.Porgit-Xci9fNpC5ZMRhJ629ycBiw==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a
05-23 15:09:40.684  3323  3323 D SoLoader: libhermes.so found on /data/app/com.matheusfinamor.Porgit-Xci9fNpC5ZMRhJ629ycBiw==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a
05-23 15:09:40.685  3323  3323 V SoLoader: libhermes_executor.so not found on /data/app/com.matheusfinamor.Porgit-Xci9fNpC5ZMRhJ629ycBiw==/lib/arm64
05-23 15:09:40.689  3323  3323 V SoLoader: libreactnativejni.so not found on /data/app/com.matheusfinamor.Porgit-Xci9fNpC5ZMRhJ629ycBiw==/lib/arm64
05-23 15:09:40.694  3323  3323 V SoLoader: libyoga.so not found on /data/app/com.matheusfinamor.Porgit-Xci9fNpC5ZMRhJ629ycBiw==/lib/arm64
05-23 15:09:40.701  3323  3323 D SoLoader: libyoga.so found on /data/app/com.matheusfinamor.Porgit-Xci9fNpC5ZMRhJ629ycBiw==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a
05-23 15:09:40.701  3323  3323 V SoLoader: libreactperfloggerjni.so not found on /data/app/com.matheusfinamor.Porgit-Xci9fNpC5ZMRhJ629ycBiw==/lib/arm64
05-23 15:09:40.707  3323  3323 D SoLoader: libreactperfloggerjni.so found on /data/app/com.matheusfinamor.Porgit-Xci9fNpC5ZMRhJ629ycBiw==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a
05-23 15:09:40.707  3323  3323 V SoLoader: libreact_render_core.so not found on /data/app/com.matheusfinamor.Porgit-Xci9fNpC5ZMRhJ629ycBiw==/lib/arm64
05-23 15:09:40.711  3323  3323 V SoLoader: libreact_render_debug.so not found on /data/app/com.matheusfinamor.Porgit-Xci9fNpC5ZMRhJ629ycBiw==/lib/arm64
05-23 15:09:40.716  3323  3323 D SoLoader: libreact_render_debug.so found on /data/app/com.matheusfinamor.Porgit-Xci9fNpC5ZMRhJ629ycBiw==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a
05-23 15:09:40.717  3323  3323 V SoLoader: libreact_render_graphics.so not found on /data/app/com.matheusfinamor.Porgit-Xci9fNpC5ZMRhJ629ycBiw==/lib/arm64
05-23 15:09:40.720  3323  3323 V SoLoader: libreact_utils.so not found on /data/app/com.matheusfinamor.Porgit-Xci9fNpC5ZMRhJ629ycBiw==/lib/arm64
05-23 15:09:40.723  3323  3323 V SoLoader: libreact_debug.so not found on /data/app/com.matheusfinamor.Porgit-Xci9fNpC5ZMRhJ629ycBiw==/lib/arm64
05-23 15:09:40.728  3323  3323 D SoLoader: libreact_debug.so found on /data/app/com.matheusfinamor.Porgit-Xci9fNpC5ZMRhJ629ycBiw==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a
05-23 15:09:40.728  3323  3323 V SoLoader: libjsinspector.so not found on /data/app/com.matheusfinamor.Porgit-Xci9fNpC5ZMRhJ629ycBiw==/lib/arm64
05-23 15:09:40.730  3323  3323 V SoLoader: libreact_featureflags.so not found on /data/app/com.matheusfinamor.Porgit-Xci9fNpC5ZMRhJ629ycBiw==/lib/arm64
05-23 15:09:40.735  3323  3323 D SoLoader: libreact_featureflags.so found on /data/app/com.matheusfinamor.Porgit-Xci9fNpC5ZMRhJ629ycBiw==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a
05-23 15:09:40.735  3323  3323 V SoLoader: libruntimeexecutor.so not found on /data/app/com.matheusfinamor.Porgit-Xci9fNpC5ZMRhJ629ycBiw==/lib/arm64
05-23 15:09:40.740  3323  3323 W linker  : "/data/app/com.matheusfinamor.Porgit-Xci9fNpC5ZMRhJ629ycBiw==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a/libruntimeexecutor.so" unused DT entry: type 0x70000001 arg 0x0
05-23 15:09:40.741  3323  3323 D SoLoader: libruntimeexecutor.so found on /data/app/com.matheusfinamor.Porgit-Xci9fNpC5ZMRhJ629ycBiw==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a
05-23 15:09:40.745  3323  3323 D SoLoader: libjsinspector.so found on /data/app/com.matheusfinamor.Porgit-Xci9fNpC5ZMRhJ629ycBiw==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a
05-23 15:09:40.748  3323  3323 D SoLoader: libreact_utils.so found on /data/app/com.matheusfinamor.Porgit-Xci9fNpC5ZMRhJ629ycBiw==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a
05-23 15:09:40.751  3323  3323 D SoLoader: libreact_render_graphics.so found on /data/app/com.matheusfinamor.Porgit-Xci9fNpC5ZMRhJ629ycBiw==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a
05-23 15:09:40.752  3323  3323 V SoLoader: libreact_render_mapbuffer.so not found on /data/app/com.matheusfinamor.Porgit-Xci9fNpC5ZMRhJ629ycBiw==/lib/arm64
05-23 15:09:40.757  3323  3323 D SoLoader: libreact_render_mapbuffer.so found on /data/app/com.matheusfinamor.Porgit-Xci9fNpC5ZMRhJ629ycBiw==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a
05-23 15:09:40.761  3323  3323 D SoLoader: libreact_render_core.so found on /data/app/com.matheusfinamor.Porgit-Xci9fNpC5ZMRhJ629ycBiw==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a
05-23 15:09:40.770  3323  3323 D SoLoader: libreactnativejni.so found on /data/app/com.matheusfinamor.Porgit-Xci9fNpC5ZMRhJ629ycBiw==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a
05-23 15:09:40.774  3323  3323 D SoLoader: libhermes_executor.so found on /data/app/com.matheusfinamor.Porgit-Xci9fNpC5ZMRhJ629ycBiw==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a
05-23 15:09:41.131  3323  3345 V SoLoader: libexpo-modules-core.so not found on /data/app/com.matheusfinamor.Porgit-Xci9fNpC5ZMRhJ629ycBiw==/lib/arm64
05-23 15:09:41.134  3323  3345 V SoLoader: libreact_nativemodule_core.so not found on /data/app/com.matheusfinamor.Porgit-Xci9fNpC5ZMRhJ629ycBiw==/lib/arm64
05-23 15:09:41.142  3323  3345 D SoLoader: libreact_nativemodule_core.so found on /data/app/com.matheusfinamor.Porgit-Xci9fNpC5ZMRhJ629ycBiw==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a
05-23 15:09:41.149  3323  3345 D SoLoader: libexpo-modules-core.so found on /data/app/com.matheusfinamor.Porgit-Xci9fNpC5ZMRhJ629ycBiw==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a
05-23 15:09:41.150  3323  3345 V SoLoader: libturbomodulejsijni.so not found on /data/app/com.matheusfinamor.Porgit-Xci9fNpC5ZMRhJ629ycBiw==/lib/arm64
05-23 15:09:41.158  3323  3345 D SoLoader: libturbomodulejsijni.so found on /data/app/com.matheusfinamor.Porgit-Xci9fNpC5ZMRhJ629ycBiw==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a
05-23 15:09:41.197  3323  3345 V SoLoader: libreanimated.so not found on /data/app/com.matheusfinamor.Porgit-Xci9fNpC5ZMRhJ629ycBiw==/lib/arm64
05-23 15:09:41.206  3323  3345 D SoLoader: libreanimated.so found on /data/app/com.matheusfinamor.Porgit-Xci9fNpC5ZMRhJ629ycBiw==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a
05-23 15:09:41.442  3323  3345 V SoLoader: libreactnativeblob.so not found on /data/app/com.matheusfinamor.Porgit-Xci9fNpC5ZMRhJ629ycBiw==/lib/arm64
05-23 15:09:41.451  3323  3345 D SoLoader: libreactnativeblob.so found on /data/app/com.matheusfinamor.Porgit-Xci9fNpC5ZMRhJ629ycBiw==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a

can you help me?
I already tried to search for gradle to check the libs but I can't open it because of the expo.
This error happened when I implemented my App.tsx, where I tested and built several apks for parts of the application and, in the last build, when I implemented the App.tsx, removing the default implementation, the crash happened.
